React query refetch with different paramerets
We have a graph. The full graph is not loaded initally. Only 1 node is loaded. User can click a buttons on the node to load successors or predecessors if applicable.
Graph was initally linear, no branching, so the previous dev did some magic with useQuery. But now there is a need forbranching tree, wher each node may have same options. I found that i cant use useQuery anymore since i cant pass params to refetch and state thing is also not viable. Any other options for this kind of thing? Maybe fetch in 1 location and get data in another?
All the nodes are handled by a parent components. While the buttons exist deep in child components. Right now, callbacks are passed through the tree.

Well, I think you can still use the useQuery function, you only need to pass the params on the queryKey to trigger another refetch on params change.
const {data: graph, isLoading} = useQuery({
    queryFn: () => fetch(params)
    queryKey: [GRAPH, params]
})

